# Section enrollments

Tags: desire2learn, valence

My Offerings, Sections and Enrollments are created through Holding Tank.
I'm trying to access lists of Users enrolled in an Offering and its Sections.
Call
    /d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/orgunits/(D2LID:orgUnitId)/users/
works OK for Offering OrgUnits, but when used on the Section ones User information is missing:
         "User": {
                "Identifier": null,
                "DisplayName": "Anonymous User",
                "EmailAddress": null,
                "OrgDefinedId": null,
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/profile/SjtASOuIHM/image",
                "ProfileIdentifier": "SjtASOuIHM"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "Student",
                "Name": "Student"
            }

Answer (score 0):

Knowing an `orgUnitId` you can get the enrolled users in the org you're "allowed to find". The `Users > View User Enrollments` permission governs whether you're allowed to pull back any enrollments, and the `Search for {roleName}` permissions govern what user records, by the name of the enrolled role, you can pull back.

The field values in the returned user records you're allowed to see are governed by the `User Information Privacy` role permissions: it seems likely that you have a set of UIP role permissions that let you see user record values for course offerings (the typical case) but *not* for the org unit type corresponding to your Section org units. Verify that you have the UIP role permissions for all the org unit types you need to search through, and that should address your issue here.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what's happened.